# .NET Core 6 API refuses to run on Port 4300

Tags: c#, .net, linux, nginx, networking

trying to setup my new server, it's an AlmaLinux 9 server with an Angular 13 FE, .NET Core 6 BE, Postgres DB, running off of nginx

So far, everything seems to be working well. My app is accessible, my DB gets my migrations (EF Code First stuff) from my app, things are happy. Problem is all of my API calls are broken with a 502 Bad Gateway error

Working through this, it seems like my API is not running on my specified 4300... but I can't really figure out why. Pretty sure this is why I'm getting the 502's.

`sudo ss -tuln | grep 4300` results in nothing

This is my nginx config

```
# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
   }

    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name  _;

        location / {
          root /var/www/html;
          try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location /api {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:4300;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/bcmx.org.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/ssl/bcmx.org.key";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Program.cs

```
using TavisApi.Context;
using TavisApi.Services;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

if (builder.Environment.EnvironmentName.Trim() == string.Empty)
  configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.Production.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(configurationBuilder.Build());

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TavisContext>(x => x.UseNpgsql(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
{
  opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
  options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
  {
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["ServerConfigs:IssuerServer"],
    ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["ServerConfigs:AudienceServer"],
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSecretKey@345"))
  };
});

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
  options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", build => build
      .WithOrigins(builder.Configuration["ServerConfigs:AudienceServer"])
      .AllowAnyMethod()
      .AllowAnyHeader()
      .AllowCredentials());
});

builder.Services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

// TODO: Let's pull out the interface hookups
builder.Services.AddScoped<IParser, Parser>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDataSync, DataSync>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITA_GameCollection, TA_GameCollection>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IBcmService, BcmService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITokenService, TokenService>();

var app = builder.Build();

var port = "4300";// Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT");
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(port))
{
  app.Urls.Add("http://*:" + port);
}

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
  var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

  var context = services.GetRequiredService<TavisContext>();
  context.Database.Migrate();
}

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseSwagger();
  app.UseSwaggerUI();
  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
  app.UseHsts();
  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapHub<SyncSignal>("/datasync");

app.Run();
```

For debugging, `curl http://localhost:4300/` (on the host server) results in `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4300: Connection refused`

I've tried different variants of configs/Program.cs to enforce it to run on port 4300.. to not luck